# Swift : How to save latitude and longitude to use in another swift file

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have this code in ViewController to capture the current location from users:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userMapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    print(location.latitude)

    let latitudeDelta : CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let longitudeDelta : CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta)

    let center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)

    let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span)

    self.userMapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    self.userMapView.removeAnnotations(userMapView.annotations)

    let userPinLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)

    let pinAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    pinAnnotation.coordinate = userPinLocation

    pinAnnotation.title = "Sua localização atual"

    self.userMapView.addAnnotation(pinAnnotation)

}
```

I have another swift file with the Database Functions, and I need save the latitude and longitude for use in database

How I store the latitude and longitude in variables to use outside the locationManager function?

Answer (score 0):

do database operations in your locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) Instance Method.
Or var a Global Model.

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is just a `Struct` containing 2 Doubles.

The very first line of your `didUpdateLocations` function extracts the current location into a local variable `location`:

```
let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
```

You could just change that from a local variable to an instance variable and it would be visible outside of that function. I'd make it an optional so it would be nil if the value was never assigned.